# how to bind optional input parameter for snowflake sql scripting procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sample(id VARCHAR,price NUMBER)
RETURNS TABLE ()
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
  select_statement VARCHAR;
  res RESULTSET;
BEGIN


  select_statement := 'SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE id = ?' ;
  
  IF (PRICE >1000) THEN
  
  select_statement := select_statement || ' AND gross_tot > ' || :price ;
  
  END IF;
  
  res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :select_statement USING (:id);
  RETURN TABLE(res);
END;
```

The price parameter is optional and need to be binded like id .
how can i bind the :price dynamically instead of concat ?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Since writing this answer, Snowflake has enabled support for optional parameters in stored procedures and UDFs:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf-stored-procedure-arguments#designating-an-argument-as-optional

You cannot specify optional parameters. You can overload functions and stored procedures in Snowflake, so that would be an alternative. Add another SP without a filter for price in addition to the one you already have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sample(id VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE ()
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
  select_statement VARCHAR;
  res RESULTSET;
BEGIN


  select_statement := 'SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE id = ?' ;
  
  //IF (PRICE >1000) THEN
  
  select_statement := select_statement || ' AND gross_tot > ' || :price ;
  
  //END IF;
  
  res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :select_statement USING (:id);
  RETURN TABLE(res);
END;
```